# How to get number of employees per year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called `Mst_Employee`. The fields are:

```
Emp_No | Emp_Name | Emp_JoiningDate | Emp_ResignedDate | Emp_Status
```

How do I get the No. of Employees by year for each year somebody joined or resigned? (Joined and Resigned includes by year)

E.g. result should look like this:

```
Year   No. of Employees.
------------------------
2011   125
2012   130
2013   100
```

Comment: please share sample data of your table. if an employee has not resigned yet then its Emp_ResignedDate will be null or you don't have such records in your table?

Comment: What if the same person was joined and resigned the same year?

Comment: Thanks Deepak, Yes if the employee yet not resigned then Emp_ResignedDate  will be null

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. If employee joined or resigned in same year or other year then count as (one)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is with a [recursive cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and group by:

```
DECLARE @FromYear int, @ToYear int

SELECT @FromYear = YEAR(MIN(Emp_JoiningDate)),
       @ToYear = YEAR(GETDATE())
FROM Mst_Employee

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT @FromYear As TheYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheYear + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE TheYear < @ToYear
)

SELECT TheYear as [Year], 
       COUNT
       (
       CASE WHEN TheYear <= YEAR(COALESCE(Emp_ResignedDate, GETDATE())) THEN 
           1 
       END
       ) As [No. of Employees.]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN Mst_Employee ON(TheYear >= YEAR(Emp_JoiningDate))
GROUP BY TheYear
```

[See fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b91fa/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with:

```
select y as [Year], count(*) as [No. of Employees.]  
from(select Emp_No, YEAR(Emp_JoiningDate) as y from Mst_Employee
     union 
     select Emp_No, YEAR(Emp_ResignedDate) from Mst_Employee 
     where Emp_ResignedDate is not null)t
group by y
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi for your query i add slightly as per my structure and got the result select y as [Year], count(*) as [No. of Employees.]  
from(select Emp_No, YEAR(Emp_JoiningDate) as y from Mst_Employee where Emp_ResignedDate is null
     union 
     select Emp_No, YEAR(Emp_ResignedDate) from Mst_Employee 
     where Emp_ResignedDate is not null)t
group by y

Comment: Dear Giorgi, Another thing i'm looking for the Columns to be display Year, No. of Joined and No. of resign please help on this.

Comment: Thanks for your query. Just what I needed