# Monthly headcount with leavers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do something similar to this thread [How to get number of employees per year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907374/how-to-get-number-of-employees-per-year)

The difference is that I need the headcount by month and also compute the number of leavers.

I have slightly modified the query so that instead of [year], I get [year-month]. So I convert the date into a string and extract the first 6 characters (YYYYMM) and convert it to an integer.

```
DECLARE @FromYear int, @ToYear int

SELECT @FromYear = 201801,
       @ToYear = convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,GETDATE(),112),6))
FROM [Airconnect].[dbo].[CoreNZ]

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT @FromYear As TheYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheYear + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE TheYear < @ToYear
)

SELECT TheYear as [Year], 
       COUNT
       (
       CASE WHEN TheYear <= convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,COALESCE([Staff_End_Date], GETDATE()),112),6)) THEN 
           1 
       END
       ) As [No. of Employees.]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CoreNZ] ON(TheYear >= convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,Start_Date,112),6)))
GROUP BY TheYear
```

I get the following message:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation in *your* question of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: you are missing a close parenthesis in "@FromYear = convert(int,(LEFT(CONVERT(char,MIN([Start_Date])),6))," ->> There are 5 open "(" characters, and only 4 ")" close...

Comment: Thanks @SQLRaptor ! I've added the parenthesis but I get the following error message:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Jun 28' to data type int.

I thought the date format in SQL was YYYYMMDD... Doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: Can you please confirm the [Start_Date] is a datetime or other date type? Since you want dates at the end, I would recommend you do something like this, which I've had success with in the past: Set all dates within a month to the first or last day of the month, e.g. all June 2019 dates are converted to 20190601... and I'll show you how:  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([Start_Date]),MONTH([Start_Date]),1)

Comment: Why don't you just use the Year(date) and Month(date) functions from sql?  Forget about all that string parsing and conversion.

Comment: `convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,GETDATE(),112),6))`. You need to convert to `yyyyMM` first. `Style` parameter is **112**.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev! I can get past the scalar setup phase with that, but still get an error message :

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: possibly duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183822/sql-server-the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-compl

Answer (score 1):

Because your year recursion exceeds the limit of recursion CTE limits(default is 100). You can change this limit by adding MAXRECURSION option.

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)
```

you can add this option end of your query.

```
DECLARE @FromYear int, @ToYear int

SELECT @FromYear = 201801,
       @ToYear = convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,GETDATE(),112),6))
FROM [Airconnect].[dbo].[CoreNZ]

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT @FromYear As TheYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheYear + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE TheYear < @ToYear
)

SELECT TheYear as [Year], 
       COUNT
       (
       CASE WHEN TheYear <= convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,COALESCE([Staff_End_Date], GETDATE()),112),6)) THEN 
           1 
       END
       ) As [No. of Employees.]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CoreNZ] ON(TheYear >= convert(int,LEFT(CONVERT(char,Start_Date,112),6)))
GROUP BY TheYear
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)
```

An additional, if you only need year and months, this version of query much better I think.

```
DECLARE @FromYear DATE, @ToYear DATE

SELECT @FromYear = '20180101',
       @ToYear = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
FROM [Airconnect].[dbo].[CoreNZ]

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT @FromYear As TheYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,TheYear)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE TheYear < @ToYear
)

SELECT TheYear as [Year], 
       COUNT
       (
       CASE WHEN TheYear <= COALESCE([Staff_End_Date], GETDATE()) THEN 
           1 
       END
       ) As [No. of Employees.]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CoreNZ] ON(TheYear >= Start_Date)
GROUP BY TheYear
```